# Calling method from Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am playing with Cocos2D on Mac.

I am using IntefaceBuilder with a NSColorWell Button. My  AppDelegate has the IBAction to set the background color in a Singleton called Settings. Then I want it to call the AnimationLayer’s method `updateBackgroundColor` for it to update. But it fails and crashes.

Why can’t I cant I message AnimationLayer method?

Since AppDelegate already knows about AnimationLayer isn't this the proper way to call a method? `[(AnimationLayer*) self methodNameHere];`

**AppDeletgate.m**

```
- (IBAction)colorwellBackground:(id)sender {
    [mySettings setBackgroundColor:[sender color]];
    [(AnimationLayer*) self updateBackgroundColor];
}
```

**AnimationLayer.m**

```
// Import the interfaces
#import "AnimationLayer.h"

// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation AnimationLayer

+(CCScene *) scene {

    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    AnimationLayer *layer = [AnimationLayer node];
    [scene addChild: layer];
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init {

    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        mySettings = [Settings sharedSettings]; 

        //DEFAULT BACKGROUND COLOR
        _backgroundColorLayer = [mySettings returnBackgroundColor];
        [self addChild:_backgroundColorLayer];


    }
    return self;
}
- (void) updateBackgroundColor{
    NSLog(@"UPDATE BACKGROUND COLOR %@", [mySettings returnBackgroundColor]);
    [_backgroundColorLayer setColor:[mySettings returnBackgroundColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your app crashes, you can always see crash reason in the console. Always add this message to your "why it crashes" questions. Actually, there is a good chance, that after reading this message you will be able to resolve your problem by yourself.

I assume that your crash message is something like "trying to call unknown method updateBackgroundColor from the appdelegate instance". In your AppDelegate class self points to the AppDelegate instance, not to your layer. If you want to call this method from your application delegate(that is actually strange for my mind), then you must somehow get current instance of your animation layer.